# Error [OpenError]: IO error: lock /opt/data/yjs-storage/LOCK: Resource temporarily unavailable

Tags: leveldb, y-websocket

Today when I start the y-websocket with leveldb storage, the y-websocket show this error log:

```
Persisting documents to "/opt/data/yjs-storage"
running at '0.0.0.0' on port 1234

/home/node/app/node_modules/levelup/lib/levelup.js:119
      return callback(new OpenError(err))
                      ^
Error [OpenError]: IO error: lock /opt/data/yjs-storage/LOCK: Resource temporarily unavailable
    at /home/node/app/node_modules/levelup/lib/levelup.js:119:23
    at /home/node/app/node_modules/abstract-leveldown/abstract-leveldown.js:38:14
    at /home/node/app/node_modules/deferred-leveldown/deferred-leveldown.js:31:21
    at /home/node/app/node_modules/abstract-leveldown/abstract-leveldown.js:38:14
    at /home/node/app/node_modules/abstract-leveldown/abstract-leveldown.js:38:14
Emitted 'error' event on LevelUP instance at:
    at /home/node/app/node_modules/levelup/lib/levelup.js:60:19
    at /home/node/app/node_modules/levelup/lib/levelup.js:119:14
    at /home/node/app/node_modules/abstract-leveldown/abstract-leveldown.js:38:14
    [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
    at /home/node/app/node_modules/abstract-leveldown/abstract-leveldown.js:38:14 {
  [cause]: undefined
```

what should I do to fixed this issue? I only opened one kubernetes pod for this service, why did this happen?